# React Router Shows Blank Page When Using <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

After updated a bunch of our dependencies we are now are forced to use anchor tags which causes redirects, before we used  but now everytime we click on a  it goes to the proper url ie /screens but is just a blank page and never presents the components, below is our parent index.tsx file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider {...stores}>
    {/* Changed routes to children */}
    {/* <Router children={routes} history={createHistory} /> */}
    <Router history={createHistory}>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/oauth2callback' componentDidMount={console.log()}>
            {() => {
              if(window.location.href.includes('/oauth2callback'))
              {
                oauth2callback(window.location.hash)
              }
            }}
          </Route>
          <Route path='/testing' component={Get} />
          <Route path='/'>
            {/* Function that determines if the user is logged in and can allow the authenticated passage or not. If no, it will not render authenticated pages*/}
            {() => {
              if(auth.loggedIn())
              {
                console.log("is logged in")
                return(
                  <div>
                    <Route component={App} history={createHistory}/>
                    <div className="row" id="wrapper">
                      <Switch>
                        {/* <Route path='/screens' component={Screens}/> */}
                        <Route path='/screens' component={Screens}/>
                        <Route path='/playlists' component={Playlists}/>
                        <Route path='/content' component={Content}/>
                        <Route path='/help' component={HelpNav}/>
                        <Route component={NotFound}/>
                      </Switch>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              }
              else 
              {
                console.log("is not logged in")
                return(
                  <Route path='/' component={HomeNav}/>
                )
              }
            }}
          </Route>
          <Route path='401' component={Get} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
```

and here is the app.tsx with the navbar:

```
 <Nav className="mb-nav">
                {/* <IndexLinkContainer to="/screens"> */}
                  <Nav.Item style={{width: widthConstants[0]}}>
                    <Link to='/screens' style={{color: this.state.navIndex === 0 ? "white" : "bbddba"}}>
                      Screens
                    </Link>
                  </Nav.Item>
                {/* </IndexLinkContainer> */}
                {/* <LinkContainer to="/playlists"> */}
                  <Nav.Item style={{width: widthConstants[1]}}>
                    <a href="/playlists" style={{color: this.state.navIndex === 1 ? "white" : "bbddba"}}>
                      Playlists
                    </a>
                    </Nav.Item>
                {/* </LinkContainer> */}
                {/* <LinkContainer to="/content"> */}
                  <Nav.Item style={{width: widthConstants[2]}}>
                    <a href="/content" style={{color: this.state.navIndex === 2 ? "white" : "bbddba"}}>
                      Content
                    </a>
                  </Nav.Item>
                {/* </LinkContainer> */}
                {/* <LinkContainer to="/help"> */}
                  <Nav.Item style={{width: widthConstants[3]}}>
                    <a href="/help" style={{color: this.state.navIndex === 3 ? "white" : "bbddba"}}>
                      Help
                    </a>
                  </Nav.Item>
                {/* </LinkContainer> */}
                {this.shouldRenderTouch && <TouchButton/>}
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
```

any idea what is different in the new react router update to cause this bug to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was much simpler than I thought, the new update integrated BrowserRouter instead of the Router so I replaced

```
<Router history={createHistory}>
```

with

```
<BrowserRouter>
```

and everything is now working as it should

Comment: And want to add this for anyone who is coming for help 
If you have a nested component. Don't use `<Router>` to wrap multiple `<Route>`s. use `< BrowserRouter>`

Answer (score 0):

Read "Routes and Links are relative to their parent" on this React Router 6 article
https://medium.com/frontend-digest/whats-new-in-react-router-6-732b06cc83e4

by the way it's strange that you have `<a>` tags instead of Link components sometimes

Comment: The <Link> is for testing purposes, they will all be <Links> eventually

Comment: ok so check the url after you clicked on your Link component, is it the url you want or not ?

Comment: Yes it is its the exact URL that it gets redirected too under the anchor tag its just like the component is not rendering

Comment: Try to change `<Link to='/screens'` by `<Link to='/testing'` is it working ? (is Get component displayed ?)

Comment: Yes it does the same exact thing, just refuses to display the component.